# Return a specific range of columns based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

sorry for my english (it's not my language)!

I need your help because I'm trying to learn how to have a formula with dynamic range of columns based on cells value.
What do I mean?

Let's take this example:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | oct |
| **2** |  | 01-OCT | 02-OCT | O1-NOV | 02-NOV | 01-DEC |  |  |
| **3** |  | a | d | a | j | m |  |  |
| **4** |  | b | a | a | k | a |  |  |
| **5** |  | c | f | i | a | o |  |  |

In cell `A1` I have the formula `=COUNTIF(x;"a")` where `x=Range of columns`, and I want to make this range based on the word I wrote on `H1`. In this case I want `x=B:C` 'cause I wrote "oct" in cell `H1`, and `x=D:E` if I wrote "nov" in it and so on!

I hope I was clear enough!

I tried looking on google and on this site, but I didn't found anything good for me...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are the values in B2:F2 actually dates?

Comment: You're talking about format? It's "General" at the moment

Comment: No, about underlaying values. Are those text looking like dates, or numbers formatted like dates. Makes a difference =)

Comment: Oh, sorry! Text looking like dates!
But I can obviously change it if needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have clarified that the values that look like dates are actually text-values, try the following:

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=SUM((B3:F5="a")*(RIGHT(B2:F2,3)=G1))
```

**Note**: If your version of Excel does not work with DA, then use `SUMPRODUCT()` instead. Also, if the values in `B2:F2` where to be dates you could use:

```
=SUM((B3:F5="a")*(TEXT(B2:F2,"mmm")=G1))
```

**Note**: For this to be able to account for more columns/rows added later on:

```
=SUM(--(TOCOL(FILTER(3:1048576,RIGHT(2:2,3)=G1),3)="a"))
```

Comment: it works! I just reopened the file and now it works!! Thank you very much!

Comment: I was fiddling around again trying to visually learn with the formulas and figured out you can leave out `TOCOL` but is this then added for performance as Excel will have less to calculate with the last part?

Comment: @Notus_Panda, absolutely the latter! Performance =)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @JvdV Hi man, can I ask you help again? ç_ç I'm trying to unify your formulas with a dynamic directory... Should I open another question?

Comment: @MrBoop, new question get new posts. However, a dynamic directory? My 1st reaction is; not possible. However you may be able to explain what it is you want/need better in a new post indeed.